# scanf causes loop to terminate early

Tags: c++, c

```
c='q';
while(c=='q')
 {
   printf("hello");
   scanf("%c",&c);
 }
```

Why does the loop exit without any reason on taking the input?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: While the question is trivial does it really deserve -5?

Comment: +1 and voting to reopen, this is ridiculous behavior from the community and you all should be ashamed.

Comment: Looks like OP is not an English speaker, no reason to close the question as not a real question. I agree with @PlatinumAzure, this is terrible behaviour by the community. +1 to the OP in hopes that this is re-opened.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question to make it a tiny bit more clear to those of us who *apparently only want native speakers asking questions here* (shame on you, you stupid xenophobes). @jatin arora, I'm sorry I had to do that but please understand I'm trying to make sure this question gets the respect it deserves, and I just wanted to make absolutely sure that no one had any reason to downvote or vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want a user input of `'q'` to mean quit, and you want the loop to exit when `c == 'q'`.

Try:

```
c='\0';
while(c !='q')
 {
   printf("hello");
   scanf("%c",&c);
 }
```

Comment: Since when can you define an empty character? Suggest using either `'\0'` or using a `do { ... } while;` loop as per T.J. Crowder's answer.

Comment: @Platinum Azure whoops. That was rather stupid of me. Thanks for that catch.

Comment: I am saying that the loop breaks even if i enter 'q' in my code...please clear it..

Answer (score 6):

The loop isn't exiting without reason. The `scanf` call will read a character from `stdin` and store it in `c`, thus changing the value of `c`. When the loop condition is tested, presumably `c` no longer `==` `'q'` (e.g., you typed something other than "q").

If you're trying to loop until the user *doesn't* type "q":

```
do {
    printf("hello");
    scanf("%c", &c);
}
while (c != 'q');
```

But note that on most console systems, `scanf` won't return until the user has typed a full line of text and pressed enter. If you're looking to do key-by-key entry, you'll probably want to look at a different function.